# parsley.js conditional form validation

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, parsley

I am using MVC with Angular JS and for validation using parsley.js(ver 2.6.2)

when i check checkbox1 then 2 textbox(txtCustomer,txtchk1 & txtchk2) should be required when submit form

when click on checkbox2 then textbox (txtCustomer & txtchk3) should required

My form is as below.

```
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCreditCard" ng-model="dvCreditCard" ng-change="alert1(dvCreditCard)" />

            Check1 required
            <input ng-model="" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtchk1" placeholder="requied if checkbox1 checked" />
            <input ng-model="" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtchk2" placeholder="requied if checkbox1 checked" />


            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCheque" ng-model="dvCheque" />
            Check2 required
            <input ng-model="" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtchk3" placeholder="requied if checkbox2 checked" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-required` directive here to make field required based on expression

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkCreditCard" ng-model="dvCreditCard"/>

Check1 required
<input ng-model="texchk1" ng-required="dvCreditCard" type="text" 
 class="form-control" id="txtchk1" placeholder="requied if checkbox1 checked" />
<input ng-model="txtchk2" type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="dvCreditCard" 
  id="txtchk2" placeholder="requied if checkbox1 checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkCheque" ng-required="dvCreditCard" ng-model="dvCheque" />

Check2 required
<input ng-model="txtchk3" type="text" ng-required="dvCheque" class="form-control" id="txtchk3" placeholder="requied if checkbox2 checked" />
```